# How to route to child from grandchild

Tags: angular, routes, angular5, url-routing

I have the following routes structure (angular 5)

```
export const ROUTES = [
    { path: "", component: ParentComponent,
        children: [
            { path: "childpath/:param1/:param2/:param3", component: ChildComponent,
                children: [{ path: "grandchildpath", redirectTo: "", pathMatch: "full" },
                    { path: "grandchildpath/:param4/:param5", component: GrandchildComponent }]
            }
        ]
    }
];
```

when in `ChildComponent` I call the route `"grandchildpath"` (no params) I would like to go to `"childpath/:param1/:param2/:param3"` but instead I get

```
Error: Cannot match any routes. URL segment: "childpath/:param1/:param2/:param3"
```

Answer (score 2):

**Relative and Absolute Navigation**
Navigation can be relative and absolute.
Relative navigation replaces a single URL segment with a different one or appends the path you specify in your `routerLink` to end of the current path.
**example:**
say your current `url` is `localhost:4200/child/1/2/3`

```
<a [routerLink]="['grandchild',4,5]">Go</a>
```

this would result in `currentpath+'/grandchild/4/5'`
  --->`localhost:4200/child/1/2/3/grandchild/4/5`

```
 <a [routerLink]="['/grandchild',4,5]">Go</a>
```

If path starts with a ‘/’, then it is an absolute navigation.

this would result in `currentpath+'/grandchild/4/5'`
  --->`localhost:4200/grandchild/4/5`

*Absolute navigation replaces the whole URL.*

When you navigate to a route using `Router.navigate()` method then you need to pass an instance of `ActivatedRoute` using `relativeTo` property because `navigate()` method is unaware of the current route.
When you navigate to a route using `RouterLink` directive, you need not pass the instance of `ActivatedRoute` because RouterLink automatically supports `ActivatedRoute`

**Solution 1:** use `routerLink` Directive 
In your child.component.html

```
<a [routerLink]="['grandchild']">Grandchild Without Param</a><br>
```

**Solution 2:**
In your child.component.ts

```
   constructor(private router:Router,private route:ActivatedRoute) { }

      ngOnInit() {
      }

     onNaviagte()
     {
       this.router.navigate(['grandchild'],{relativeTo:this.route});
     }
```

**[`Live Demo`](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-routing-redirects)**

Comment: Hi, If the provided answer has solved your question please consider accepting it.